# Sort rows of a 2d array by column value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => some title
            [time] => 1279231500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => some title 2
            [time] => 1279231440
        )
    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => some title 3
            [time] => 1279229880
        )
)
```

How I can sort it based on time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort it this way (since it is an associative array):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
   return strcmp($a['time'], $b['time']);
}

usort($your_array, "cmp");
print_r($your_array);
```

Comment: any idea how to reverse the order?

Comment: @greenbandit - Change the comparison function to `return strcmp($b['time'], $a['time']);` - usort() is sorting based on `cmp()`.

Comment: @reverse: Either return `-1 * strcmp(...);` or apply `array_reverse` after sort.

Comment: You should not use `strcmp` for integer values. Because `2 < 12` but `strcmp(2, 12) === 1` that means “`2` is greater than `12`”.

Answer (score 1):

As Gumbo mentioned, you should not use strcmp for integer values.

Use this function

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['time'] == $b['time'])
        return 0;
    return ($a['time'] < $b['time']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: For integer values, `return $a['time'] - $b['time'];` would suffice.